# how to update the products in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2.7

I am using Magento 2.2.7 we are developing one selling medicines website so I have first imported the 300 medicines now I want to add the 1000 medicines how to update the medicines my dought is deleting the 300 medicines after import the 1000 medicines? or updating the medicines how to do that?

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you. It will help others too.

Answer (score 5):

Magento 2 Provide the Import Behaviour "Add/Update".So Magento 2 is ovverwrite the 300 products so you can not require deleting the 300 products.you can directly import 1000 products

[image]

Comment: ok i can understnd but the issue is product name is same and sku is same how to do that?

Comment: please tell me solution  @Hardik Makwana

Comment: Hello, 
Magento 2 is override the same prodcut name and sku.

Comment: First Import the Product If any error occured then tell me

Comment: 1. Url key: 'atorfit-cv-10.html' was already generated for an item with the SKU: '168'. You need to specify the unique URL key manually in row(s): 36
2. Url key: 'atorfit-cv-20.html' was already generated for an item with the SKU: '169'. You need to specify the unique URL key manually in row(s): 37
3. Url key: 'atorsave-d-10.html' was already generated for an item with the SKU: '173'. You need to specify the unique URL key manually in row(s): 38

Comment: SKU and product name is already in their database now I want to update the SKU and if the product is there in database update the product

Comment: Please set the Import behavior : "Add/Update" and if not working then delete this product URL key

Comment: I have done the import behavior: Add/Update and but product key url erros is 43 errors. so every key URL is deleting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94339/discussion-between-hardik-makwana-and-parshuram).

Answer (score 3):

If you import CSV with same SKU and import behaviour is Add/Update, then those products will be updated. And if that SKU does not exist, new product will be created with given data. So you don't need to delete everytime when you import CSV (with same or different SKU).